# Ambiguity in converting to correct DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I've encountered a problem in which I am looking for a good solution.

Consider I have a node that passes data with corresponding date with the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`

For example: `OK 2020-08-23` (Time is omitted)

And in the destination node I do parse `Date` by simple code

```cs
Convert.ToDateTime(date)
```

Recently I we noticed that destination node not properly handles date and looks it has Ambiguity in parsing date correctly

For example : if I pass data Like `OK 2020-08-23` it works correct as because it knows that number of months never exceeds from 12 so 23 is day and 08 is month. However, when data is `OK 2020-02-03` it don't know *02* is month or *03*?

*How can I resolve this Ambiguity in a proper manner?*

Comment: This is basically ISO date format. DateTime.Parse should parse it without problem. I just tried your second example, and it properly parses it as a 3rd day of second month.

Comment: @Tom as matter of fact i have simplified the problem in order to explain the main problem. there some third party node which date might not be compatible and so on. but i know that there are some problems with my date format and parsing.

Comment: @Tom so i decide to put a parsing role in order to eliminate parsing issues.

Comment: Well, you oversimplified, so the question isn't really the problem you have. As the quote says 'Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `ParseExact` method and specify a custom format you need to parse:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(theDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

The method has an overload where you can pass a format provider

```
var dtFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
string result = Convert.ToDateTime("12/01/2011", dtFormat);
```

Comment: your solution looks nice but i have some problems with that which is, it doesn't provide exactly the format i need for example 12/01/2011 or 12-01-2011